# Kryonet problems with basic setup

Tags: java, android, networking

Ive been trying to get my android connecting to pc. so i could learn some more networking. when im following github tutorials and do exactly they say everything goes shit. ive made like 20 diffrent variations and all suck :D

my client is actually good so it has to be problem how my server handles it.
But its weird because i have listener for connection and it dosent connect.

i downloaded huge server somewhere in internet and my client actually connected it. but it was huge i couldnt undrestand why :D

Networking is hard! (or just kyronet lol)

ive made couple games using libgdx and android studio i just wanna learn networking. ive theres some good guides for kyronet what works appreciated!

ERROR

```
05-11 13:41:29.625 26636-26657/? W/connecting: zzz
05-11 13:41:37.636 26636-26656/com.mygdx.game.android E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Client
                                                                        Process: com.mygdx.game.android, PID: 26636
                                                                        com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.KryoNetException: Error during deserialization.
                                                                            at com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.TcpConnection.readObject(TcpConnection.java:141)
                                                                            at com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Client.update(Client.java:247)
                                                                            at com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Client.run(Client.java:333)
                                                                            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
                                                                         Caused by: com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Buffer underflow.
                                                                        Serialization trace:
                                                                        connectionID (com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.FrameworkMessage$RegisterUDP)
                                                                            at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField$ObjectIntField.read(ObjectField.java:201)
                                                                            at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:551)
                                                                            at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:793)
                                                                            at com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.KryoSerialization.read(KryoSerialization.java:58)
                                                                            at com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.TcpConnection.readObject(TcpConnection.java:139)
                                                                                ... 3 more
                                                                         Caused by: com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Buffer underflow.
                                                                            at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Input.require(Input.java:199)
                                                                            at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Input.readVarInt(Input.java:373)
                                                                            at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Input.readInt(Input.java:368)
                                                                            at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField$ObjectIntField.read(ObjectField.java:197)
                                                                                ... 7 more
05-11 13:41:37.656 26636-26652/com.mygdx.game.android I/AndroidGraphics: paused
05-11 13:41:37.656 26636-26636/com.mygdx.game.android I/AndroidInput: sensor listener tear down
05-11 13:41:37.656 26636-26636/com.mygdx.game.android I/AndroidGraphics: Managed meshes/app: { }
05-11 13:41:37.656 26636-26636/com.mygdx.game.android I/AndroidGraphics: Managed textures/app: { }
05-11 13:41:37.656 26636-26636/com.mygdx.game.android I/AndroidGraphics: Managed cubemap/app: { }
05-11 13:41:37.657 26636-26636/com.mygdx.game.android I/AndroidGraphics: Managed shaders/app: { }
05-11 13:41:37.657 26636-26636/com.mygdx.game.android I/AndroidGraphics: Managed buffers/app: { }
05-11 13:41:37.675 26636-26652/com.mygdx.game.android I/AndroidGraphics: destroyed
05-11 13:41:39.641 26636-26657/com.mygdx.game.android W/System.err: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connected, but timed out during TCP registration.
05-11 13:41:39.641 26636-26657/com.mygdx.game.android W/System.err: Note: Client#update must be called in a separate thread during connect.
05-11 13:41:39.641 26636-26657/com.mygdx.game.android W/System.err:     at com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Client.connect(Client.java:161)
05-11 13:41:39.641 26636-26657/com.mygdx.game.android W/System.err:     at com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Client.connect(Client.java:104)
05-11 13:41:39.641 26636-26657/com.mygdx.game.android W/System.err:     at com.mygdx.game.android.ConnectClient2$2.run(ConnectClient2.java:45)
05-11 13:41:39.641 26636-26657/com.mygdx.game.android W/CANT CONNECT: ERROR
05-11 13:41:39.643 26636-26657/com.mygdx.game.android I/art: System.exit called, status: 1
05-11 13:41:39.643 26636-26657/com.mygdx.game.android I/AndroidRuntime: VM exiting with result code 1, cleanup skipped.
```

on first try

first try as client >

```
package com.mygdx.game.android;

import android.util.Log;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;
import com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo;
import com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Client;
import com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Connection;
import com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Listener;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;

/**
 * Created by 112944 on 25.1.2016.
 */
public class ConnectClient {

    private SomeRequest request;
    private SomeResponse response;
    private Client client;
    public NetworkDATA network;
    private String name;

    private String ipAddress;
    private int tcpPort, udpPort;

    private MMORPG game;

    public ConnectClient(MMORPG game){
        this(NetworkDATA.SERVER_IP, NetworkDATA.SERVER_TCP_PORT, game);

    }
    public ConnectClient(String ipAddress, int tcpPort, MMORPG game) {



        this.ipAddress = ipAddress;
        this.tcpPort = tcpPort;
        //this.udpPort = udpPort;
        this.game = game;


    }





    public void runClient() {
        client = new Client();
        network.register(client);
        Log.w("client started", "started");
        // For consistency, the classes to be sent over the network are
        // registered by the same method for both the client and server.
        client.addListener(new Listener() {
            public void connected(Connection connection) {
                Log.w("connected", "connected");
                NetworkDATA.RegisterName registerName = new NetworkDATA.RegisterName();
                registerName.name = name;
                client.sendTCP(registerName);
            }
        });

        client.start();

        Thread fuckingCONNECT;
        fuckingCONNECT = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Log.w("connecting", "zzz");
                    client.connect(9999, ipAddress, tcpPort, 54777);
                    // Server communication after connection can go here, or in Listener#connected().
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    Log.w("CANT CONNECT", "ERROR");
                    System.exit(1);
                }
            }
        }; fuckingCONNECT.start();
    }
}
```

then i tried

```
    package com.mygdx.game.android;


import android.util.Log;

import com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo;
import com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Client;
import com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Connection;
import com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Listener;

import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Created by astraali on 11.5.2017.
 */


public class ConnectClient2 {

    private Client client;
    public NetworkDATA network;

    public void startclient(){
        Log.w("connet program started", "started");
        client = new Client();
        Kryo kryo = client.getKryo();
        kryo.register(SomeRequest.class);
        kryo.register(SomeResponse.class);
        client.addListener(new Listener() {
            public void received (Connection connection, Object object) {
                if (object instanceof SomeResponse) {
                    SomeResponse response = (SomeResponse)object;
                    System.out.println(response.text);
                }
            }
        });

        client.start();

        Thread fuckingCONNECT;
        fuckingCONNECT = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Log.w("connecting", "zzz");
                    client.connect(9999, "10.0.2.2", 54565);
                    //client.connect(9999, "10.0.2.2", 54563, 54777);
                    // Server communication after connection can go here, or in Listener#connected().
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    Log.w("CANT CONNECT", "ERROR");
                    System.exit(1);
                }
            }
        }; fuckingCONNECT.start();
    }
}
```

server

```
package server;


import java.io.IOException;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo;
import com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.KryoSerialization;
import com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Connection;
import com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Listener;
import com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Server;
import server.SomeRequest;
import server.SomeResponse;
import common.Network;



public class GameServer extends ApplicationAdapter {

    static int SERVER_TCP_PORT;
    static int SERVER_UDP_PORT;

    Server server;

    public GameServer () throws IOException {


        server = new Server();

        Kryo kryo = server.getKryo();
        kryo.register(SomeRequest.class);
        kryo.register(SomeResponse.class);


        //server.bind(54555, 54777);
        System.out.println("Started server!");
        server.addListener(new Listener() {
            public void received (Connection connection, Object object) {
               if (object instanceof SomeRequest) {
                  SomeRequest request = (SomeRequest)object;
                  System.out.println(request.text);

                  SomeResponse response = new SomeResponse();
                  response.text = "Thanks";
                  connection.sendTCP(response);
               }
            }
        });
        server.bind(54565);
        server.start();
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //SERVER_TCP_PORT = Network.SERVER_TCP_PORT;
        //SERVER_UDP_PORT = Network.SERVER_UDP_PORT;

        new GameServer();



}
}
```

Comment: I'm going to gamble and invest some deeper meaning in "Client#update(int) must be called in a separate thread during the connection process." I notice you don't override it, I will at least trap for it. I don't see how I can arbitrarily call it while in the `connect` library call so that's about as much as I can do.